# Where to import 'reflect-metadata' in Next.js 14.1.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tsyringe

I'm trying to use [tsyringe](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe) 
for dependency injection in my Next.js 14.1.0 app. I'm using the new
[App Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app). But for some reason it isn't working correctly when doing `import 'reflect-metadata';` at the top of my [Root Layout.](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#root-layout-required).

It's still throwing the following error on some pages:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: tsyringe requires a reflect polyfill. Please add 'import "reflect-metadata"' to the top of your entry point.
```

Any ideas where should I import this polyfill? I thought the Root Layout was Next.js 14 entry point but it seems it ain't.

Comment: Do it at your main file

Comment: I have no "main" file. And the root layout.tsx doesn't seem like an entry point either.

Comment: Would [tsyringe issue 180](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe/issues/180#issuecomment-1908609050) be of interest in your case?

Comment: @VonC nope :( it's not related

Comment: share your code it's hard to debug this kind of question without it

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it would be great if you could share your code and why you want to use `dependency injection`. Probably, there could be better and cleaner way to do what you want to do.

However, if you must use `dependency injection`, try following

```
// app/layout.tsx
import 'reflect-metadata';
import ClientLayoutComponent from '@/app/ClientLayoutComponent';

export default function RootLayout({
  children
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <ClientLayoutComponent />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

```
// app/ClientLayoutComponent.ts
'use client';

import 'reflect-metadata';

export default function ClientLayoutComponent(): null {
  return null;
}
```

Reference - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/46805#discussioncomment-8261261

You may be facing issues with app router because of the React Server components. By above approach we make sure we are importing the library on client side as well.

Comment: Yes I've tried this. But it's still throwing the error. It only works for some pages doh..

Comment: Can you please share your code

Comment: Please try this as well - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/46805#discussioncomment-8261261 (No client component - just the script)

Comment: also didn't worked

Comment: Please share your code. Let us try to debug.

Comment: It's a simple question. Where can I import polyfills into a next 14 app using the app router? Please see https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49850 for more context

Comment: If you're not willing to share any code with us, then it will be hard to help :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was that the polyfill is required to be injected to the entry point of **client** part of your code, and it seems like root layout is server side, so what you need to do is to import the polyfill in the client side. One idea is to wrap the root children with a `<ClientRoot>` component:

```
// ClientRoot.tsx, the children wrapper
"use client";
import React from "react";

import "reflect-metadata"; // add polyfill in client side

export default function ClientRoot({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return <>{children}</>;
}
```

Then update the root layout file to this:

```
// layout.tsx, entry point
import "reflect-metadata"; // add polyfill in server side
import ClientRoot from "./ClientRoot";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <ClientRoot>{children}</ClientRoot>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Tested this in my local machine with next 14.1.0, and it works.

Comment: this is the same answer as @Techno Verse

Comment: @Carlos Dubón are you sure? This one wraps the children, their answer makes a sibling

Comment: yes I've tried both aproaches. And on some pages I still get the error.

Comment: @CarlosDubón can you make sure that those pages that still got error uses the same root layout? I know it doesn't make sense, but I'd guess those pages don't have the same root layout or the tsyringe codes that you use on those pages are run separately. It might be good if you could include the code one of the pages that still got error in the question, especially the tsyringe parts

Comment: yes they are on the same root. this doesn't work :((

Answer (score -1):

In a Next.js application, the entry point is typically the `_app.tsx` file located in the `pages` directory. This file is responsible for initializing your application and serves as the wrapper component for all pages.

To ensure that `reflect-metadata` is imported at the correct entry point, you should add the import statement `import "reflect-metadata";` at the top of your `_app.tsx` file. This ensures that the polyfill is loaded before any other code in your application.

Here's an example of how you can modify your `_app.tsx` file:

```js
// _app.tsx

import 'reflect-metadata'; // Import the reflect-metadata polyfill
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```